# Hoe to get all work items from Visual Studio Team Services REST API

Tags: .net, tfs, azure-devops

I need to fetch 5000> work items on daily basis and need to prepare some report but REST API  support only 200 slot at a time and in that case I will have do many call to API. Is there any other way to get all work items at once ???

Answer (score 1):

Which version of TFS are you using? If you are using on-premise TFS 2018 or VSTS, then you can use the REST API - [Reporting Work Item Revisions - Read Reporting Revisions Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) or [Reporting Work Item Revisions - Read Reporting Revisions Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20post?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get all the work items:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=4.1
```

You can add optional parameters as needed:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?fields={fields}&types={types}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&startDateTime={startDateTime}&includeIdentityRef={includeIdentityRef}&includeDeleted={includeDeleted}&includeTagRef={includeTagRef}&includeLatestOnly={includeLatestOnly}&$expand={$expand}&includeDiscussionChangesOnly={includeDiscussionChangesOnly}&$maxPageSize={$maxPageSize}&api-version=4.1
```

For example, we can use below PowerShell script to retrieve all the work items from a specific project (You can also export the result to a `*.csv` file, then open in Excel):

```
Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection", 
   [string]$projectName = "0511ScrumTFVC",
   [string]$user = "domain\user",
   [string]$token = "password/PAT"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true"
Write-Host $uri
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
Clear-Host
Write-Host "Count of Work items"$result.values.count 
$wits = @()
foreach ($wit in $result.values)
{

$customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WitID" = $wit.fields.'System.id'
          "rev" = $wit.Rev
          "Title" = $wit.fields.'System.Title'
        } 

    $wits += $customObject
}

$wits | Select `
                WitID,
                rev, 
                Title #|export-csv -Path D:\temp\WITs.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: @Kabir Have you resolved the issue by the solution? any update?