# Get WorkItems from Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, workitem

I'm having some troubles to get all Work Items. I want to get all of the Test Cases ( they are more than 300), but unfortunately I can get only 187 of them.

```
$uri = "/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2"
$workItems = $response | Where-Object ({$_.fields.'System.WorkItemType' -eq 'Test Case'})
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52154896/hoe-to-get-all-work-items-from-visual-studio-team-services-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vito Liu-MSFT

I tried with batches [Work Items - List][1] . Devided 10 000 items to 50 different groups and queried them. Working fine and gives me back the result I want.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Hi Baequiraheal, thanks for the sharing, you could mark it as an answer, In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can add the field `maxPageSize` to specify the maximum number of results to return in the result.
Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/reporting%20work%20item%20revisions/read%20reporting%20revisions%20get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for more details

Sample url:

```
$uri = "/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&$maxPageSize={$maxPageSize}&api-version=6.0-preview.2"
```

**Update1**

As test result, the maximum number is 1000

[image]

Comment: The things is there are more than 10 000 work items and I think the revision is not going to work. I shows me only 998 work items.

Comment: Hi Baequiraheal,
Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.